# How to display Summation in TableView in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is it possible to display information in TableView as given in screenshot?

Here: 'MyFund' is sum of amounts of Rob, Mike and Sam Fund.

I am not sure how will I sum up the amounts and display in Table headers.

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. I suppose you could calculate the summation in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` as such:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // replace the following with however you'll calculate the sums
   int sumSectionOne = 4;
   int sumSectionTwo = 3;

   return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",sumSectionOne], [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",sumSectionTwo], nil];
}
```

but it does mean you'll be invoking `reloadSections` **a lot** on that table view. Moreover, this isn't entirely the intended purpose of UITableView (though admittedly a really easy way of doing this).

Answer (score 0):

There is no sort cut for this you need to implement a good store data structre then a logic to fetch them.so its all about logic,see my approach.

You need to add this record in an array with dictionary form,means add fund with money in a dictionary with two different key says "fund" and "money"(any thing).

when you make section means in `titleForHeaderInSection` method, you need to implement the logic.you need to make loop upto array count and access the dictionaries and add all "money" values.

Now you need to implement.if you have face any problem in code then again ask.